# Selecting an inputted number of files from a folder

Tags: python

I have a folder with a few hundred thousands data files in it. And what I want to do is separate the data into groups of n (which will be inputted by the user) in a way that allows me to manipulate just that group of data. Then I want to start back where I left off in the folder and take another group. For example if n was 5 I would want files 1-5 to be read and manipulated then I'd like to have 6-10 read and so on and so forth.

```
def fileavg(path,n):
  import numpy as np
  import xlsxwriter
  from glob import glob

  workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test.xlsx')
  worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
  row=0

 b=glob.iglob(path) #when inputting path name begin with r' and end with a'
 for i in range(0,len(b),n):
     f=yield [i:i +n]
     A=np.mean(f(1),axis=1)
     for col, data in enumerate(A):
         worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)
     row +=1
```

I have tried using a for loop and the yield keyword but I was having a problem with a generator error. I would like to continue using the for loop with just a different technique of grabbing the data.

Updated Code

```
def fileavg(path,n):
 import numpy as np
 import xlsxwriter
 import glob


 workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test.xlsx')
 worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
 row=0
 more_files=True
 b=glob.iglob(path) #when inputting path name begin with r'and end with a '


 while more_files:
     for i in range(n):
         try:
             next_file=next(b)
             print(row,next_file)
             A=np.mean(next_file(1))
         except StopIteration:
             more_files=False
             break
        
         for col, data in enumerate(A):
             worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)
         row +=1
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your best attempt at writing this code.

Answer (score 0):

`iglob` returns an **iterator** not an **iterable**, so it does not have a length. The easy way to grab the next n items from an iterator is to use `itertools.islice`.

```
import glob
from itertools import islice

num_items = 5

b=glob.iglob(path) #when inputting path name begin with r' and end with a'

next_n_files = list(islice(b, num_items))
```

If you really want to use a for loop for this, then you can use `next()` to grab the next item. You'll have to maintain a flag that triggers once the `next()` function runs out of files and raises a `StopIteration` exception. When this exception is raised, we need to break out of the for loop that grabs the n files and also change the flag to exit the while loop. For grouping, we use the `row` variable to keep track of each group.

```
import glob
from itertools import islice

num_items = 5

b = glob.iglob(path)

row = 0

more_files = True

while more_files:

    for i in range(num_items):
        try:
            next_file = next(b)
            print(row, next_file)
            # Do other stuff with file here
        except StopIteration:
            more_files = False
            break

    
    row += 1
```

Comment: I've updated my code and am receiving an error indicating the '"list' object is not an iterator"

Comment: Could you show your updated code on your post?

Comment: Yes I have edited it into the OP

Comment: Yeah, you're combining the two approaches, which is unnecessary and mixing you up. Either use `islice` and then just use `next_n_files[index]` to get a file from that batch or use `next` on the iterator like in the second example. Lists are iterables and not iterators and do not use `next`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I run the updated code I'm now getting a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in line 25: A=np.mean(next_file(1)). I've ried changing the variable names and I continue getting the error is there anything else that could resolve this type error

Comment: `next_file` is just a string with the name of the file, so `next_file(1)` makes no sense. What are you trying to do with that line?

Comment: I only want to use the second row of the array in my averaging

Comment: Then you need a line to actually open the file. What you are doing is only listing the file names and iterating through them. What you need to use to open the file will depend on the file format.